# Total number of unread messages for all chats in Applogic SDK

Tags: android, applozic

I am using applogic chat sdk and want the count of unread messages for a user, i need to show the same as a count on my notification icon in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to get the total unread count

```
int totalUnreadCount = new MessageDatabaseService(context).getTotalUnreadCount();
```

Refer this link for docs for total unread count [link](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/android-unread-count#section-total)